# How to clear a variable like `sy[0]` in mathematica?

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica

The example is like this

```
sy[0] = 0
Clear[sy[0]
```

Though I `clear` `sy[0]`, when I Input:

```
sy[0]
```

It still outputs:

```
0
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: I've downvoted this.  The very short interval between asking the question and answering your own question indicates a deviant approach to solving programming questions: first ask SO, second study the problem and read the documentation.  A much better approach is first study the problem and read the documentation, second ask SO.

Answer (score 0):

I see..

`ClearAll[sy]` works for me.

Or `sy[0] =.`